# MultiByteToWideChar or WideCharToMultiByte and txt files

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I'm trying to write a universal text editor which can open and display ANSI and Unicode in EditControl. Do I need to repeatedly call `ReadFile()` if I determine that the text is ANSI? Can't figure out how to perform this task. My attempt below does not work, it displays '?' characters in EditControl.

```
LARGE_INTEGER fSize;
        GetFileSizeEx(hFile,&fSize);

        int bufferLen = fSize.QuadPart/sizeof(TCHAR)+1;
        TCHAR* buffer = new TCHAR[bufferLen];       
        buffer[0] = _T('\0');

        DWORD wasRead = 0;
        ReadFile(hFile,buffer,fSize.QuadPart,&wasRead,NULL);        
        buffer[wasRead/sizeof(TCHAR)] = _T('\0');

        if(!IsTextUnicode(buffer,bufferLen,NULL))
        {                       
            CHAR* ansiBuffer = new CHAR[bufferLen];
            ansiBuffer[0] = '\0';
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,buffer,bufferLen,ansiBuffer,bufferLen,NULL,NULL);
            SetWindowTextA(edit,ansiBuffer);
            delete[]ansiBuffer;
        }
        else
            SetWindowText(edit,buffer);

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        delete[]buffer;
```

Comment: Notepad++'s source code might be relevant as a reference: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few buffer length errors and oddities, but here's your big problem. You call `WideCharToMultiByte` incorrectly. That is meant to receive UTF-16 encoded text as input. But when `IsTextUnicode` returns false that means that the buffer is not UTF-16 encoded.

The following is basically what you need:

```
if(!IsTextUnicode(buffer,bufferLen*sizeof(TCHAR),NULL))
    SetWindowTextA(edit,(char*)buffer);
```

Note that I've fixed the length parameter to `IsTextUnicode`.

For what it is worth, I think I'd read in to a buffer of `char`. That would remove the need for the `sizeof(TCHAR)`. In fact I'd stop using `TCHAR` altogether.  This program should be Unicode all the way - `TCHAR` is what you use when you compile for both NT and 9x variants of Windows. You aren't compiling for 9x anymore I imagine.

So I'd probably code it like this:

```
char* buffer = new char[filesize+2];//+2 for UTF-16 null terminator
DWORD wasRead = 0;
ReadFile(hFile, buffer, filesize, &wasRead, NULL);        
//add error checking for ReadFile, including that wasRead == filesize
buffer[filesize] = '\0';
buffer[filesize+1] = '\0';
if (IsTextUnicode(buffer, filesize, NULL))
    SetWindowText(edit, (wchar_t*)buffer);
else
    SetWindowTextA(edit, buffer);
delete[] buffer;
```

Note also that this code makes no allowance for the possibility of receiving UTF-8 encoded text. If you want to handle that you'd need to take your `char` buffer and send to through `MultiByteToWideChar` using `CP_UTF8`.

Comment: Be careful. [`IsTextUnicode()` can report false results](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/01/30/363308.aspx). [Notepad uses `IsTextUnicode()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx) to detect file encodings and it gets it wrong on occasion. You should not rely on `IsTextUnicode()`, and should not make assumptions about a file's encoding. If there is a BOM present, it tells you the file's encoding, so look for that first. If there is no BOM present, ask the user what the encoding is, don't try to guess it, because you are likely to guess wrong at times.